# Selenium Python There are 2 span tags in a html table td column, how do i get the 2 values out

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a html table with some rows and columns.
In column 6 there are 2 span tags in a single td tag.  Each span tag has a value.
The row in the table with the **value 4 in column 6** and the value 24 in column 6
I would like to get the **value 4 and 24** out where **column 2 has the text all_matches_filtered** and where **column 4 has the text Do_Name and Do_Name2**

In my Selenium Python script I will be verifying if the values 4 and 24 are there for the text all_matches_filtered and the text Do_Name and Do_Name2

What XPath can i use to locate the value 4 and 24 please?

I have made a start with an Xpath and it locates the value 4 for the text all_matches_filtered.  I would like to include the text Do_Name which is in the same row as value 4

My Xpath is:

```
//table[@id="reporting_reports_ct_fields_body"]//tr//td//div//span[contains(text(), "all_matches_filtered")]/following::td[6]//div//span[(text()="4")]
```

The HTML snippet is (I have shortened the html otherwise it will be quite long):

```
<table id="reporting_reports_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG GJPPK2LBMG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-2169" style="outline-style:none;" tabindex="0">
            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-2170" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="linkhover" title="all_matches_filtered"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">all_matches_filtered</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-2171" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="manual"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">manual</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-2172" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="linkhover block" title="Do_Name"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Do_Name</span>
            <span class="linkhover block" title="Do_Name2"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Do_Name2</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-2173" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="This is a matches report"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">This is a matches report</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-2174" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="USN entities"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">USN entities</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-2175" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span title="16/03/2016 10:36:45"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">16/03/2016 10:36:45</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-2176" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="block" title="" style="">4</span>
            <span class="block" title="" style="">24</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH GJPPK2LBNG">
</tr>
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
</tbody>
```

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriverFirefox()  # driver = webdriverChrome()
driver.get('inser_page_URL_where_table_located')
table_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG"]')[-1]
values = []
for i in table_data.find_elements_by_tag_name('span'):
    values.append(i.text)
print values
```

and let me know if any exceptions occured

Comment: I get the error     table_data = self.driver_find_element_by_xpath(By.XPATH, '//td[@class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG"]')[-1]
AttributeError: 'ReportsPage' object has no attribute 'driver_find_element_by_xpath'

Comment: I have the table id, for table_data it would be better to use the table id instead of the xpath.  The table id is 'reporting_reports_ct_fields_body'

Comment: No, you should use `driver.find...` instead of `driver_find...`

Answer (score 0):

First at all get right row for
*out where column 2 has the text all_matches_filtered and where column 4 has the text Do_Name and Do_Name2*

this would be:

```
/table[@id="reporting_reports_ct_fields_body"]//tr[
  td[2]//span[contains(text(), "all_matches_filtered")] and 
  td[4]//span="Do_Name"
]
```

and form here the right column (for example)

```
/td[8]//span
```

which than is something like:

```
//table[@id="reporting_reports_ct_fields_body"]//tr[td[2]//span[contains(text(), "all_matches_filtered")] and td[4]//span="Do_Name"]/td[8]//span
```

Comment: This is close, it has highlighted the block where name is all_matches_filtered. There are 4 names here, Do_Name, Do_Name2, Name_DOB nad Name_Tel

Comment: Can i use an Xpath to get just the value 4 for all_matches_filtered, Do_Name.  I can then use the xpath again seperatley to get the value 24

Comment: @RiazLadhani sure: to get only one value, you may change the last part to e.g. `/td[8]//span[1]` or [2] (if you are expecting two span. and for the Do_Name use contains for td[] like for td[2]  (`... and td[4]//span[contains(text(), "Do_Name") ]`